# Why EXC_BAD_ACCESS does not happen?

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

I create a single mutable string object. Now I have released the object many times, even though I allocated them only once. According to basic memory management rules, this is wrong. But then it should crash, but this never happens. I was expecting some EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I received the error :

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x6d5ac60: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Why the app does not crash?

```
NSMutableString *firstOwner = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[firstOwner release];
[firstOwner release];
[firstOwner release];
NSMutableString *temporaryObject = firstOwner;
[temporaryObject release];
[temporaryObject release];
```

Comment: You have told the memory management system that you don't need that block of memory any more.  After that, it may or may not use it for some other purpose.  There's no rule that guarantees it will be set to some value that causes a crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because a crash doesn't happen for you doesn't mean it won't happen for somebody else.

You're just illustrating a case where the app can continue to limp along after making memory management errors. The crash may not be happening because aside from blatantly over-releasing, you're not doing anything else with the object references.

But if you attempted to use or access "`firstOwner`" or "`temporaryObject`" later, you'd absolutely crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS then and there.  Access to non-existent or over-released objects are a primary cause of these kinds of crashes.